# How to insert and update in 3 different databases?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have 3 different databases, `database1, database2, and database3`.

I have a table `Account` in each databases. Inside my `database1` and `database2` table `Account`, I have 3 columns, `ID, Username, and Password` and inside my database 3 table Account I have 4 columns `ID, Username, Password, and db_name`

What I want to do is to insert all of `database1.Account` and `database2.Account` data in `database3.Account` and in my 4th column, I need to identify where database it came from.

By the way, I have already made it but I am not satisfied with my solution because I spend 3 queries for that. As much as possible, I want to make it with just 1 query If it is possible.

P.S: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: have you tried any sql or coding?

Comment: so what problem you are facing ...have you tried anything from ur side

Comment: instead of directly getting solution, you should try and search something

Comment: Can you tell us the type of `db_name`?

Comment: My db_name is just a Varchar

Comment: Which database is MySQL and which is MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using union you can achieve this.

```
INSERT INTO database3.dbo.Account (ID, Username, Password,db_name)
SELECT ID, Username, Password,'database1' FROM database1.dbo.Account
UNION
SELECT ID, Username, Password,'database2' FROM database2.dbo.Account
```

Comment: I have done that using UNION but my real problem is to identify the name of the database it came from. If it is from Database1 or Database2.

Comment: Last column db_name of database3.dbo.Account will have that.

Comment: Yes! I'm sorry. I didn't notice :) Seems that I have found the right answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
INSERT INTO database3.account(ID,Username,Password, db_name)
SELECT ID, Username, Password, "1" FROM database1.account
```

Then do

```
INSERT INTO database3.account(ID,Username,Password, db_name)
SELECT ID, Username, Password, "2" FROM database1.account
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO database3.dbo.Account (ID, Username, Password,db_name)
   SELECT ID, Username, Password,'database1'
     FROM database1.dbo.Account 
     WHERE (some condition)


INSERT INTO database3.dbo.Account (ID, Username, Password,db_name)
   SELECT ID, Username, Password,'database2'
     FROM database2.dbo.Account 
     WHERE (some condition)
```

Comment: It's just an option,if there is any filtering criteria

Comment: There is no filtering